# Error in Deploying IOS App

Tags: ios, xcode8, info.plist

When I am trying to deploy my IOS app to apple store I am getting the following error:Error ITMS-90684:"The info.plist file as AppName.app/www/node_modules/mocha/editors/javascript mocha.tmbundle/info.plist is currently named info.plist,Info.plist file name is case-sensitive and must be exactly named as 'info.plist' I tried to modiy the name of the file manually no luck serach for the value of info.plist with small i in the whole project I coudnt find it

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on Appname.app and click on Show package contents you can see node_modules folder then you can solve your problem.

apart from this it seems that you installed the node js by command "nm installed" in your project directory.